# Вывод сообщения в канал

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Мне необходимо создать функцию которая отправляет сообщение в определённый канал. Уточняю, канал НЕ должен быть указан пользователем и не должен являться местом отправки сообщения.
То есть, варианты с:

```
@client.command()

async def test(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.send('Test')
```

и

```
@client.command()

async def test(ctx):
    channel = discord.Message.channel
    await channel.send('Test')
```

не предлогайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу дать более простой и понятный код.

С сообщением указанным в аргументе

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, text):
    channel = bot.get_channel(#айди канала)
    await channel.send(text)
```

С фиксированным сообщением:

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(#айди канала)
    await channel.send(#ваше сообщение)
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вот такой вот костыль, но прекрасно работает если не создавать новых каналов или не менять их месторасположение.
P.S. *Отсчет расположения начинается с 0*

```
guild = ctx.guild #наш сервер
category = guild.categories[4]  #позиция категории
channel = category.channels[0]  #позиция канала в категории
await channel.send(...)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили!

Answer (score 0):

```
# ID нужного канала
channel_id = 0

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await (await ctx.guild.fetch_channel(channel_id)).send(ctx.message.content)
```